# How to call a method having parameter "context"

Tags: android, android-context

How to call a method having parameter "context"

```
Class Abc {

private static synchronized void int d() {

abcd();
```

//How to call this method ? if i add abcd(context) it won't work, 
    do i need to initialize context again ? if yes How ?

```
}

public static void abcd(Context context){
//I am doing something
}

}
```

Comment: pass your activity context as a parameter...

Comment: abcd(getApplicationContext);

Comment: abcd(Abc.this); if Abc is an Activity.

Comment: Thanks, Priyank, And.Dev, Alexey. But mine class is not activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Abc` class extends an `Activity`, then you are able to call `getApplicationContext()` method:

```
abcd(getApplicationContext());
```

If `Abc` does not extend `Activity` you should make a setter method inside your `Abc` class:

```
class Abc {

    private Context mContext;

    //...

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
//...
}
```

Then call it from an activity:

```
Abc abc = new Abc();
abc.setContext(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Good blogpost about context types and applicability scopes http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/ because it's not enough to put "just a context", it's better to put correct one :)

Comment: Thanks Kidoki, Mine is simple class and not activity and I just tried to do the same way you explained. But as abcd is static method "this.context" is not working. Can you put up something incontext to that ?

Comment: Yuri, Thanks, That was really helpful link.

Comment: Thanks Kidoki, It worked, only thing i had to do was define "private Context mContext" as static "private static Context mContext" because the methods where i was calling was static. I am not sure if declaring "context" static is right approach....anyway...till it works i don't have any problem ;) Thanks once again